# Center a vertically oriented grid in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I started doing the UI for an app in WinForm but I just read about WPF and I decided to re-do my work on it. But since is a new think I ran in a small problem:

As you can see in the screenshot bellow I have 3 vertical buttons that are centered on the main form. How can I achieve the same thing in WPF? I've tried any value I could find to change position but all of them failed.

[image]

Here is my main form XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="YouTubeMusicPlayerWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YouTubeMusicPlayerWpf"
        xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="500" Width="900" Background="Black" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="true" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="mainWindow">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="6" CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="0">
        </WindowChrome>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <StackPanel Background="#FF201E2B">
        <!-- TitleBar buttons -->
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button fa:Awesome.Content="WindowMinimize" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="8" BorderThickness="0" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Name="minButton" Click="MinButton_OnClick"></Button>
                <Button fa:Awesome.Content="WindowMaximize" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="8" BorderThickness="0" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Name="maxButton" Click="MaxButton_OnClick"></Button>
                <Button fa:Awesome.Content="WindowClose" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="8" BorderThickness="0" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Name="closeButton" Click="CloseButton_OnClick"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <!-- Menu Buttons-->
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button fa:Awesome.Content="Youtube" FontSize="40" Background="#00000000" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                <Button fa:Awesome.Content="Music" FontSize="40" Background="#00000000" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
                <Button fa:Awesome.Content="Download" FontSize="40" Background="#00000000" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your root element. Replace the StackPanel by a grid and problem solved.

Bonus : if you are new to WPF, I show you how to refactorize your styles.

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--  Exemple of a style with a key to reuse  -->
        <Style x:Key="LeftButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <!--  TitleBar buttons  -->
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <!--  Exemple of a implicit styles that will be set to each child with a matching type  -->
            <!--  Notice there is no x:Key  -->
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button Content="b1" />
        <Button Content="b2" />
        <Button Content="b3" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!--  Menu Buttons  -->
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="icon" Style="{StaticResource LeftButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Content="icon" Style="{StaticResource LeftButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Content="icon" Style="{StaticResource LeftButtonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Notice there is neither RowDefinitions nor ColumnDefinitions.

Here is how to do the same thing with place to set the content (a red box for exemple).

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--  Exemple of a style with a key to reuse  -->
        <Style x:Key="LeftButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00000000" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--  TitleBar buttons  -->
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Column="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <!--  Exemple of a implicit styles that will be set to each child with a matching type  -->
            <!--  Notice there is no x:Key  -->
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button Content="b1" />
        <Button Content="b2" />
        <Button Content="b3" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!--  Menu Buttons  -->
    <StackPanel
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="icon" Style="{StaticResource LeftButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Content="icon" Style="{StaticResource LeftButtonStyle}" />
        <Button Content="icon" Style="{StaticResource LeftButtonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Background="Red" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer and for the bonus. The red box example helped a lot at this moment to bring the UI close to what I had in winForm